# Flex 3 using nested states

Tags: flex3, states

Im using states in my flex form application.

The base state is the regular form. I then have an advanced form button which calls the advanced state. Once inside the advanced state form if a user enters invalid data an error will be displayed using another error state which just adds a text field to the lastChild element of the advanced state,

the problem im having is that when the error state is kicked off, instead of displaying the error below the advanced form it instead goes back to the base state.

Is it possible to calls a state from inside another state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with states, but judging from the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/states/State.html), isn't that what the `basedOn` attribute of the `State` object is for?

Answer (score 0):

you can check out the flex states tutorial here :

http://askmeflash.com/tutorial/0/how-to-create-website-in-flex-tutorial-my-first-flex-website